# Add new rows/columns to a table

Tags: javascript, html-table, tablerow

I have this code already:

```
for (i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var col = document.createElement('td');
    col.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));
    row.appendChild(col);
    document.getElementById('imagenametable').appendChild(row);
}
```

This is in Javascript. It does not seem to be adding anything to my table (which has an ID of `imagenametable`. What is wrong? And yes, I do intend to just make rows of text in a table.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle where this doesn't work? I plugged your code into one and got rows... (http://jsfiddle.net/zrcaR/) Are you sure names has something in it?

Comment: Make sure the DOM is loaded when your code runs. Put it in a function and put that in `<body onload="yourfunc()">`.

Comment: Well, on my page, `$(document).ready()` does not work either. maybe it has something to do with that? I just put it in the `js` file without a `document.onload` or `$(document).ready()` or anything like that. If I just put an `alert` it works fine.

Comment: Here is the HTML: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YeZ77WNr

Comment: CSS: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U5Huwu45

Comment: JS: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eEiWK8SD

Comment: Is the above script in project.js? Since it's loaded in the head, it runs before the body is finished loading, so imagenametable isn't in the DOM yet. Since you're using jQuery, put your code inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: @Barmar but `$(document).ready()` does not work for some reason in my JS

Comment: for example, if I have this: `$(document).ready(function() { alert('test'); });` it does not alert 'test' like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inverse the two script tags : always load your libraries before any other scripts that uses them.