# $(document).ready() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
var names = [
    'Abstract',
    'Animals',
    'Beach',
    //etc. (removed because it was too long)
    'Volcano'
];

var links = [
    'http://i.imgur.com/MFkuQ.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/QEt72.png',
    'http://i.imgur.com/nmrqv.jpg',
    //etc. (removed because it was too long)
    'http://i.imgur.com/7uy15.png'
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test');
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var col = document.createElement('td');
        col.appendChild(document.createTextNode(names[i]));
        row.appendChild(col);
        document.getElementById('imagenametable').appendChild(row);
    }
});

function expandbar(s) {
    resetbars();
    $('#' + s).show('slow');
}
function resetbars() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $('#sec' + i).hide('slow');
    }
}
```

The `$(document).ready()` is not working; I do not get an alert that says 'test' when my page loads. Help?

I have included jQuery.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the JavaScript console, or in the Chrome or IE debugger, or the Firebug plugin for Firefox?

Comment: Excuse me for asking the obvious, but have you included the jquery script on your page?

Comment: Try changing it to `jQuery(document).ready(....`. If that works, then something has overridden the `$` symbol.

Comment: @G_M that is not valid syntax - you mean `jQuery(function() { ... })` or jQuery(document).read(fuinction ... )`

Comment: yes of course I included JQuery :P

Comment: and if what G_M says is the culprit, you can pass $ in function($) to allow use of $ within the ready call... jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... })

Comment: This did not work either: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ alert ('test'); })`

Comment: Welp, I guess it's time to check the old error console to see what JavaScript error is causing the script to be aborted!

Comment: Did you do as @Pointy said and check one of the debuggers for js errors? (And Pointy meant firebug for fire*fox*)

Comment: um, does Komodo edit have a debugger? and latest version of JQuery, yes.

Comment: Works for me, alert and all. http://jsfiddle.net/esqew/ASRn6/

Comment: also, is this all the js within this particular script tag?

Comment: Don't debug in the editor, debug in the browser.

Comment: yes. `<script type="text/javascript" src="project.js"></script>` and the code I posted is `project.js`.

Comment: can you link me to a chrome debugger?

Comment: Are you sure you're including jQuery __before__ this script?

Comment: It's built into Chrome: View->Developer->Developer Tools

Comment: All of the other JQuery stuff works, so that's not it

Comment: Seems to be working in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZrTZA/7/

Comment: Just right-click somewhere on the page in chrome and pick "inspect element"

Comment: But the other jQuery stuff is inside functions, and they don't run until some event invokes them.

Comment: The problem might be becoz of someother code...

Comment: Use the console and isolate the issue.  Comment out everything but the alert and see if that works.  Uncomment until it works.  This may be the faster way until you learn how to use the console more effectively.

Comment: We have many similar comments here, please reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: You should have described your code in a detail. Also you should have shown what are the imports made and how it is made.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="project.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

should be:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="project.js"></script>
```

The script has to be loaded AFTER jQuery.

I found this code in http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YeZ77WNr which he posted in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867533/add-new-rows-columns-to-a-table)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a closure to the whole thing:

```
(function($){

   // do stuff.... 

})(jQuery);
```

With this you don't need to to call `$(document).ready()` and you make sure your `$` doesn't conflict with any other library. Just make sure it is right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work if jquery is not properly included **or** there is some error in your javascript code. [including in any js files included]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#q").keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) 
        alert('in');
});
```

});

It wasn't working since there was some error in one of js file I included in head.

**Solution? Directly use your code** if you already have DOM loaded. Or place it where it can access DOM [in footer]

```
<script>
$("#q").keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) 
        alert('in');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {  })(jQuery);
```

or

```js
window.onload = function() {
    /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript in head tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('calll');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include JQuery if you are missing it. The same issue was resolved of mine by just including JQuery Script.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```